# In a Mongoose Schema return "parent" collection specific value

Tags: node.js, schema, express, return-value, mongoose

What I need is to return a specific "parent" value from a Schema method:

I have two Schemas:

```
var IP_Set = new Schema({
    name: String
});
```

and

```
var Hash_IP = new Schema({
    _ipset      : {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'IP_Set'
    },
    description : String
});
```

In the `Hash_IP` schema I would like to have the following method:

```
Hash_IP.methods.get_parent_name = function get_parent_name() {
    return "parent_name";
};
```

so when I run:

```
var hash_ip = new Hash_IP(i);
console.log(hash_ip.get_parent_name())
```

I can get the `IP_Set` name value of the associated `Hash_IP` instance.

So far I have the following definition, but I can't manage to return the name:

```
Hash_IP.methods.get_parent_name = function get_parent_name() {
    this.model('Hash_IP').findOne({ _ipset: this._ipset })
        .populate('_ipset', ['name'])
        .exec(function (error, doc) {
            console.log(doc._ipset.name);
        });
};
```

I've tried:

```
Hash_IP.methods.get_parent_name = function get_parent_name() {
    this.model('Hash_IP').findOne({ _ipset: this._ipset })
        .populate('_ipset', ['name'])
        .exec(function (error, doc) {
           return doc._ipset.name;
        });
};
```

without results.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you're very close. Your question isn't very clear on this, but I assume that

```
.populate('_ipset', ['name'])
.exec(function (error, doc) {
  console.log(doc._ipset.name);
});
```

is working and

```
.populate('_ipset', ['name'])
.exec(function (error, doc) {
   return doc._ipset.name;
});
```

is not?

Unfortunately the async `return` is not working the way you want it to.

`.exec` calls your callback function, which returns the name. This does not return the name as the return value for `get_parent_name()`, though. That would be nice. (Imagine the `return return name` syntax.)

Pass in a callback into `get_parent_name()` like this:

```
Hash_IP.methods.get_parent_name = function get_parent_name(callback) {
    this.model('Hash_IP').findOne({ _ipset: this._ipset })
        .populate('_ipset', ['name'])
        .exec(callback);
};
```

You can now use `instance_of_hash_ip.get_parent_name(function (err, doc) { ... do something with the doc._ipset.name ... });` in your code.

### Bonus answer ;)

If you use your parent's name a lot, you might want to always return it with your initial query. If you put the `.populate(_ipset, ['name'])` into your query for the instance of Hash_IP, then you won't have to deal with two layers of callbacks in your code.

Simply put the `find()` or `findOne()`, followed by `populate()` into a nice static method of your model.

#### Bonus example of bonus answer :)

```
var Hash_IP = new Schema({
    _ipset      : {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'IP_Set'
    },
    description : String
});

Hash_IP.statics.findByDescWithIPSetName = function (desc, callback) {
    return this.where('description', new RegExp(desc, 'i'))
        .populate('_ipset', ['name']) //Magic built in
        .exec(cb)
};

module.exports = HashIpModel = mongoose.model('HashIp', Hash_IP);

// Now you can use this static method anywhere to find a model 
// and have the name populated already:

HashIp = mongoose.model('HashIp'); //or require the model you've exported above
HashIp.findByDescWithIPSetName('some keyword', function(err, models) {
   res.locals.hashIps = models; //models is an array, available in your templates
});
```

Each model instance now has models._ipset.name already defined. Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks for the bonus answer! :) What you noted in your first answer is exactly what I need. I want to do this in a way that I don't need to pass a callback as you point in the example of Hash_IP.methods.get_parent_name method because other app requirement :( Can you post a bonus example of your bonus answer :D. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I almost forgot: +1 for the bonus answer hehehe :D

Comment: I accepted your answer because is technically correct due my question but I ended up adding the ipset_name into de Hash_IP schema as the parent reference, and removed the _ipset variable. In that way I will not suffer anymore hahahaha :D Thanks.